# How can I change multiple filenames simultaneously in Vim?

Tags: vim

I have a season of a show downloaded and every episode filename ends with information about the video ([1080p], [Dual Audio], etc). I would like to use Ctrl-V to simply rename all of the files at once, but this seems to be harder than I feel it should...

For starters, I hit the:
'E21: Cannot make changes, 'modifiable' is off'
To which I enter:
:set ma

Then upon editing said files I'm greeted with the:
'W10: Warning: Changing a readonly file'

This seems to be quite inconvenient for me. 
Any solutions y'all can point me towards? Much appreciated!

Comment: So you're looking to rename files in netrw or NerdTree? It might be better to use perl rename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Fern.vim](https://github.com/lambdalisue/fern.vim) can actually do this by selecting the nodes with `-` and then calling the rename action. You'll be presented with a buffer with each file/folder on one line. Whatever edits you make to the paths will be the resultant destination. Pretty nifty honestly.

https://github.com/lambdalisue/fern.vim#renamer-action-aka-exrename

Answer (score 0):

The nerdtree view is just a text representation of the files themselves, so you can't just edit the text there. What you can do is perhaps use rename command `mm`, but it will not allow you to bulk rename files in a convenient manner.

Might be worth checking out other tools, like scripting (perl/python...), or some other tool like midnight commander `mc`

Comment: I'll be sure to check them out, thanks.

It should have been obvious to me, knowing that NerdTree is a file viewer haha